# Python replace word in string base on position

Tags: python, string

I working on a project to correct grammatically wrong sentence to correct one.
How do I use python to replace the word in between 2nd and 3rd space to the correct one?

I need the search for what to replace to be the position not search for exact word and replace it.

```
S = "Nothing is absolute right or wrong ."

Position -> 2 and 3 (this position is the position of space to replace the word between 2nd space and 3rd space)
Replace "absolute" with "absolutely"
```

Comment: your used tags has nothing to do with your question. Also you should show your own approach. If you hadnt any idea, maybe try a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66598947/how-to-make-translating-function-in-python)

Comment: Why use "|||" as the separator instead of just "|"?

Comment: the dataset i found online use ||| as separator, so I have to work with this

Comment: You can picture what has to be done, right?  Read the first string.  Use `words = s.split()` to divide it into words.  Use `words[position] = replacement` to fix it.  Use `' '.join(words)` to build the new sentence.

Comment: take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/66605152/7865368