# replacing only the first occurance of a character in string

Tags: python

My objective is to replace the 0th string element with another string element. I tried the below code.

```
s='12:15:45'

s=s.replace(s[0],'9')

print(s)
```

While the 0th element does get replaced, the change is also reflected on the 3rd element.

output-
92:95:45

Why is this happening ?

Comment: use `s.replace(s[0],'9', 1)` to replace only the first occurrence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The replace function by default is replacing all the occurrences of `1` in the string. You can limit this using the correct syntax as below

Syntax

`string.replace(oldvalue, newvalue, count)`

If you want only the first occurrence to get replaced you should use

`s=s.replace(s[0],'9',1)`

Answer (score 1):

use `s.replace(s[0],'9', 1)` to replace only the first occurrence.

---

> [`str.replace(old, new, count)`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)
> Return a copy of the string with **all** occurrences of substring
> `old` replaced by `new`. If the optional argument `count` is given, only
> the first `count` occurrences are replaced.

Answer (score 1):

Pass count of occurrance.

```
string.replace(oldvalue, newvalue, count)
```

- `oldvalue`   Required. The string to search for
- `newvalue`   Required. The string to replace the old value with count
- `count`      Optional. A number specifying how many occurrences of the old value you want
  to replace. Default is all occurrences

s=s.replace(s[0],'9',1)

print(s)

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the docs:

> **str.replace(old, new[, count])** - Return a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional
> argument count is given, only the first count occurrences are
> replaced.

You don't specify `count`, so it replace **all occurrences** of `s[0]` - in this case `'1'`. In this particular case you can do

```
s = '12:15:45'
s = s.replace(s[0],'9',1)
print(s)
```

but it will not work always - e.g. if you want to replace only `s[3]`